# Problem while importing a module from a subfolder

Tags: python

I have a problem with importing a module from a sub folder. 
I am running the main code from directory `C:\Users\yeosiz\Desktop\bert_on_stilts`. Folder `glue` is inside the mentioned directory and my main code is calling `tasks.py` inside the `glue` folder. I want to import `get_task`and `MnliMismatchedProcessor` from `tasks.py`.

The structure of the directory:

```
bert_on_stilts
|_ main.py 
|_ glue
    |_tasks.py
```

Here is the code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Users/yeosiz/Desktop/bert_on_stilts/glue')
from glue.tasks import get_task, MnliMismatchedProcesso
```

But I get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'glue.tasks'`.
I am using python 3.6. Moreover, there is `__init__` in the `glue` folder.

I have checked the following links to find the solution but I couldn't solve the problem 
[Python 3 import class from subfolder problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958196/python-3-import-class-from-subfolder-problem), [Import module from subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder), and [import main file (not another module) from a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294847/import-main-file-not-another-module-from-a-subfolder)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changes in import statement python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
from tasks import get_task, MnliMismatchedProcesso
```

or use:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Users/yeosiz/Desktop/bert_on_stilts')
```

Otherwise, the glue is doubled.

Answer (score 0):

you need to start the import with a relativity dot notation so it would be

```
from .glue.tasks import get_task, MnliMismatchedProcesso
```